# PHP Variables not Posting

Tags: php

So pretty much this is my code. It's not generating any sort of post. Is there some reason why this is occuring? It's rather annoying. And is getting on my nerves.

I've been trying to de-bug this for about 30 minutes now. And I've tried numerous things. Is it because of it not actually posting the values? Or is it just not reading them properly?

```
echo $_POST["sntype"];
```

And here is the form code:

```
$htmloutput1 = '<html>
<body>
<form name="sntype" action="site.php" method="post">
<select>
  <option value="1">Please Choose...</option>
  <option value="Elect">Electronics</option>
  <option value="Food">Food</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</select>

</body>
</html>';

echo $htmloutput1;
echo $_POST["sntype"];
```

Comment: You should name the <select> not the <form>...

Comment: @Keeper Post it as an answer

Comment: Please show us all  the code.

Comment: That is all the code. I only trimmed out what I had commented out earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `</select>` is placed outside of the `<form>` and the `<input>` is inside the `<select>` as a result.

```
<form name="sntype" action="site.php" method="post">
<select>
  <option value="1">Please Choose...</option>
  <option value="Elect">Electronics</option>
  <option value="Food">Food</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</select>
```

How about trying this instead:

```
<form name="sntype" action="site.php" method="post">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Please Choose...</option>
    <option value="Elect">Electronics</option>
    <option value="Food">Food</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT** Also, what do you expect to get from `echo $_POST["sntype"];`? That is simply the name of the form: `sntype`. That is not the value of the `<select>`. And `<select>` has no name.  So why not set this:

```
<form name="sntype_form" action="site.php" method="post">
  <select name="sntype">
    <option value="1">Please Choose...</option>
    <option value="Elect">Electronics</option>
    <option value="Food">Food</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I changed the name of the `<form>` to be `sntype_form` and set `<select>` to now be `<select name="sntype">` so the name is now `sntype`.

Comment: Nope. That's how it was set up at first, then I was so confused I tried moving everything around to see if I had forgotten the placement of the </select>. I just tried it again to make sure.!

Comment: You also miss the name of the `select` field :)

Comment: I see that his form name is `sntype`. So most probably he wants to print the whole form data ;) Or he has just made a mistake naming the form instead of a certain input field :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so lots of problems with your code.

Try the following:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["sntype"])){ //if sntype was submited
    echo $_POST["sntype"];
}
else{ //otherwise display form
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="sntype">
      <option value="1">Please Choose...</option>
      <option value="Elect">Electronics</option>
      <option value="Food">Food</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

**Issues with your code**

- Ensure all fields are in the `FORM` tag
- Each field you want to submit should have the `name` attribute
- I'm not sure what you want to achieve with the code but the above should get you going